# Recommendations for DNSSEC key metadata

Tags: keys, dnssec, metadata

In order to implement `auto-dnssec maintain` in the 9.7+ versions of BIND, one adds dates to the keys as metadata. After a lot of reading, I've come up with the following and hope that someone can confirm or correct it:

```
$TTL 8h
KSK lifespan == 1y
ZSK lifespan == 30d

Key    created  published    active        revoke       inactive   delete
KSK1                         [KSK0 revoke] [active      [revoke    [inactive
                                            + lifespan]  + 2*TTL]   + 2*TTL]
KSK2            [KSK1 revoke [KSK1 revoke]
                 - 2*TTL]
```

ZSKs would follow a similar pattern.

The most difficult requirement is the graceful rollover of the KSKs and ZSKs. I understand that there is a need for overlap while a pair of KSKs or ZSKs are used simultaneously, but I need help with the proper size of those overlaps.

Doubling up on the number of ZSKs (during overlap) must double the number of `RRSIG` records and consequently almost double the size of the query responses. This is quite subjective; but does this double load ever become significant?

Presumably, the creation and deletion of the KSK DS records should correspond with the 'published' and 'delete' dates of the keys?

Comment: I just found the `-S` option for `dnssec-keygen` which provides some values for some of these.